# Is there a way to flag compiler to ignore unused imports?

Tags: go, compiler-errors

If the compiler can recognize that an import is unused, then is it possible to set it to continue with compilation without that import ?

Even if it's not possible, what are the pros/cons of such an option ?

Comment: No, but there are some third party options. This one is popular with a lot of folks I know (personally I don't like these tools) https://packagecontrol.io/packages/GoImports - only works with Sublime3 though.

Comment: I removed your edit about the duplicate. Your suggestion is good and could probably be posted to meta.stackoverflow.com, but does not directly relate to this posted question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. For reasoning see the following FAQ:

[FAQ: Can I stop these complaints about my unused variable/import?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#unused_variables_and_imports)

> The presence of an unused variable may indicate a bug, while unused imports just slow down compilation, an effect that can become substantial as a program accumulates code and programmers over time. For these reasons, Go refuses to compile programs with unused variables or imports, trading short-term convenience for long-term build speed and program clarity.
>
> Still, when developing code, it's common to create these situations temporarily and it can be annoying to have to edit them out before the program will compile.
>
> Some have asked for a compiler option to turn those checks off or at least reduce them to warnings. Such an option has not been added, though, because compiler options should not affect the semantics of the language and because the Go compiler does not report warnings, only errors that prevent compilation.
>
> There are two reasons for having no warnings. First, if it's worth complaining about, it's worth fixing in the code. (And if it's not worth fixing, it's not worth mentioning.) Second, having the compiler generate warnings encourages the implementation to warn about weak cases that can make compilation noisy, masking real errors that *should* be fixed.
>
> It's easy to address the situation, though. Use the blank identifier to let unused things persist while you're developing.

What you may do is use the blank identifier when temporarily want to exclude something, e.g.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    _ "time"  // This will make the compiler stop complaining
)
```

> Nowadays, most Go programmers use a tool, [goimports](http://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports), which automatically rewrites a Go source file to have the correct imports, eliminating the unused imports issue in practice. This program is easily connected to most editors to run automatically when a Go source file is written.

Comment: I'm beginning to understand why this language is described as 'opinionated'. Nothing that I mind so far though.

Comment: Really, it was necessary to create a separate tool `goimports` to fix this problem? Also, `_ "time"` is effectively the same as `// "time"` and is annoying either way. I do like most of the decisions they made on Golang, but this one smells.

Comment: Also if this was such a concern they should still make it a warning during tests, and only an error during production compilation.

Comment: +1 to the answer, but I'd -1 the quoted rationale if I could for its asinine omission of several actually relevant considerations. For example, the inability to ignore unused imports makes iterative development way more of a pain in the ass than it needs to be - for example I routinely include everything I intend to use in the `import` block when starting a new file, but then want to iteratively compile and test each piece of functionality that I implement in the file - Go forces me to keep adding/removing `_` or `//` to imports manually, or to keep around and run a tool that does it.

Comment: I mean I get it - if you give people something just because it is useful in development, inevitably someone will rely on it in production. But still. Really increases the obviously unnecessary tedious overhead that didn't have to exist between me and what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @mtraceur Go set up its goals that includes writing simple, readable software that scales. Forbidding unused imports aligns with that. We're not talking about a software that is made of 4 source files and totals 1000 lines of code. If you're considering thousands of files and millions of lines, having unused imports in all of them does make a difference. Saying it's a hassle having to use a tool to ease this is just an excuse. I hardly ever have to touch imports because my IDE takes care of it automatically. It's no hassle at all for me, no more hassle than in other languages.

Comment: @icza I also don't understand why you would want to make that comment defending Go's decisions like that unless you somehow took my original comment personally even though the only thing aimed at you in it was the "+1 to the answer".

Comment: @icza I do agree that allowing unused imports doesn't scale - which should be obvious because as I said in my second comment that "if you give people something [...], inevitably someone will rely on it in production". Which is why my second comment started with an "I get it" - they couldn't include it, because of the bigger picture of how human usage of programming languages scales. The problem I was pointing out is that they failed to express that in their stated rationale, which I think matters a lot more for justifying limitation than what they did say.

Comment: Saying that a hassle is not a hassle because the IDE hides it sounds like a step in a bad direction, which ironically is what Go's design was trying to avoid.