# Go import returns "unused import"

Tags: go

I'm newbie with goLang. I'm trying to build a project from **intellij** that use a package from git library using:

```
import (
    "github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go"
)
```

but I'm getting: "unused import"

I've set my **gopath** into `\users\myuser\go` and added it into **intelij** settings, but I'm getting now `unused import` and the project does not recognize the 3rd party objects.

Should I import the module into my solution? I see that it exist in the file system: `\users\myuser\src\github.com\aerospike\aerospike-client-go`

Can you assist me?

Thanks

Comment: What's your GOPATH? Can you give us the *exact* error you get?

Comment: i've set my gopath into \users\myuser\go & add it into intelij settings. but i get now unused import and the project does not recognize the 3rd party objects. should i import the module into my solution? i see that it exist in the file system: \users\myuser\src\github.com\aerospike\aerospike-client-go

Comment: Hi, If you got error `unused import` it means that you're not using library and must use it. GoLang has quite strict standarts on that. For dependency managing you can use `golang/dep` package. 

And yes it's enought to have package inside GOPATH to use it as import.

Comment: And what do you mean by `does not recognize 3rd party objects`

Comment: `unused import` means an import that was not used. :-)

Comment: Don't forget to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer and https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote, for this or your other questions.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing a package that you are not using; your compiler is trying to prevent this to keep performance up.

Just remove:

```
import (
    "github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go"
)
```

and it should compile.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792281/is-there-a-way-to-flag-compiler-to-ignore-unused-imports?noredirect=1&lq=1) for more.